# What does "to fall to upon" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs, literary-english

> And they **fell to upon** their frugal supper.

(From [*Vanity Fair*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a8NJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA324&dq=%22they+fell+to+upon+their+frugal+supper%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEnpiwvY3TAhVCDcAKHRPOBGQQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22they%20fell%20to%20upon%20their%20frugal%20supper%22&f=false))

I can only find either **to fall *to***, or **to fall *on* / *upon***, but never **to fall to on / upon**.

Comment: It probably parses as *they (fell to) (upon their ...)*. It may help for you to post more context.

Comment: to my ear, it sounds more of a British idiom than a US idiom... or perhaps a dated or affected American idiom.  I could imagine a professor from Haaaavaaard using this construct more easily than I could imagine a casual, 'normal' person using it in the US...however if a Harry Potter character said it..even a student.. it would seem right. My 2cents.. perhaps otehrs would differ .. Good explanations in the answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a literary  idiomatic expression, often used referring to eating:

***[Fall to (on/upon)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+to)***:

> - Energetically begin an activity, set to work, as in *As soon as they had the right tools, **they fell to work on the house***.
> - This expression is also often used to mean "begin to eat." Charles Dickens so used it in American Notes (1842): ***"We fall-to upon these dainties.***" [Late 1500s]

(AHD)

Usage Examples

From: [Robin Hood/King Arthur's Knights](https://books.google.it/books?id=dsBtAdgoLtYC&q=%22fell%20to%20upon%22&dq=%22fell%20to%20upon%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitqfvbpI3TAhUMJ8AKHf5rDScQ6AEIHDAA):

> - So we quarrelled, and by and by ***we fell to upon that fight*** in which thou did see us engaged."

From [Sea-cursed](https://books.google.it/books?id=euBZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22fell%20to%20upon%22&dq=%22fell%20to%20upon%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitqfvbpI3TAhUMJ8AKHf5rDScQ6AEIUjAI):

> - I have already mentioned, and ***so fell-to upon a very hearty supper***; but, as we ate, each man had his weapon stuck in the sand beside him; for we had knowledge that the valley held some devilish thing....

More usage examples are available in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall%20to%20upon%2Cfell%20to%20upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20to%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfell%20to%20upon%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Thank you. Does "AHD" mean The American Heritage Dictionary?

Comment: Very useful, indeed. Is this idiomatic usage still in use today?

Comment: @user26328 - It is idiomatic usage, it is a  literary expression, not  very common now I'd say, see here for other examples: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall+to+upon%2Cfell+to+upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20to%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfell%20to%20upon%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you. Clear now. As they would have said back in the day when they used to fall to upon their meals, you're a capital fellow, you are. (To be sure, English is not my native language).

Comment: A similar phrase is [set to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/set-to_1) which means to commence to do something with determination or enthusiasm... _"After the third complaint, he set to repairing the leaky faucet"_

Comment: @barbecue But can you say "They set to upon their meal"?

Comment: @user26328 No, you'd drop the "to." So phrasing it that way would be "They set upon their meal." Again, it's a literary device. Saying it that way would be akin to "They attacked their meal." Generally you're indicating that the group of people are very hungry, and are eating more to sate that hunger than to savor the meal itself. Even "fall to upon" looks to be an archaic usage; every link I'm seeing looks to be from the 1800s. Today you'd see it as "to fall upon."

Comment: @user26328 actually, you could say "they set to upon their meal" but it would probably mean that they got into a fight on the dinner table. Set to means to dive in enthusiastically, but is also often used to mean a fight or argument. My point in mentioning it was that it's a similar verb phrase combining a verb with to.